# How to pass data from a BroadcastReceiver from a second activity to a function in another activity

Tags: android

I need to send a data from a BroadcastReceiver from a second activity to a function in another activity but I do not know how to do it, someone could tell me how to do it.

This is the BroadcastReceiver of a second activity:

```
public class UsbService extends Service implements SerialPortCallback {    

private boolean statusUSB = false;

private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)) {
            boolean ret = builder.openSerialPorts(context, BAUD_RATE,
                    UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8,
                    UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1,
                    UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE,
                    UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
            if(ret){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Usb Conectado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                statusUSB = true;
            }else{
                statusUSB = false;
            }

        } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)) {

            UsbDevice usbDevice = arg1.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            boolean ret = builder.disconnectDevice(usbDevice);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Usb Desonectado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
            arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
};
.
.
.
```

The data I need to send is the Boolean statusUSB

This is a function of the first activity where I need to receive it to evaluate it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.
.
.
    public boolean checkUSB() {

    if (statusUSB == true){
        Toasty.success(this, "USB Conectado!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
     }
    if (statusUSB == false){
        Toasty.error(this, "USB Desconectado!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not something the Android dev model supports.  Each `Activity` is independent with its own lifecycle (see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).)  You do not directly call methods in an `Activity` from another `Activity`.  If your 2nd `Activity` is being used to gather information which then needs to be reported to the 1st `Activity`, look into starting the 2nd `Activity` [for result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)).  Your 2nd `Activity` then just needs to set the result before it calls `finish()`.